# Batch convert svg 1.0 to 1.2

Tags: javascript, php, shell, svg

I am working with some CAD software that exports files in SVG 1.0 which has more data than is needed, and is breaking when I try importing it into some things. When I import into illustrator and export as SVG 1.2 everything works great.

Is there a way to batch convert hundreds of SVG 1.0 to 1.2? There are dozens of ways to do so from SVG to PNG, AI, JPG and so on, but I just want to update the version of SVG.

I have available to me CentOS, Ubuntu, Mac, PC, and all the standard web services (LAMP / Node).

Comment: There should be very little difference. In fact 1.0 should be better supported that 1.2 because SVG 1.2 introduced a number of features that were never widely supported by anything.  Can you attach an example of a 1.0 file that causes problems?  We may be able to help then because currently your question is light on useful detail.